# Get variable from function to public class

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I want to get a variable from a function into a class.

The code below is my class and I want to get `var.status` into public class.

```
package
{    
    public class GetJson
    {
        public var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        public var status:String = "notlive"; // i want to get status var to here

        public function GetJson()
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://myurl.com/json.json");
            loader.load(request);

            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, jsonLoaded);
        }

        public function jsonLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            var jsonContent:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            var data:Object = JSON.parse(jsonContent.data);
            var status = data[0].status; // This the variable that i want to get up there
            trace(status);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined `status` as a variable in your class:

```
public var status:String = "notlive";
```

When referencing that variable, call it as `status` or `this.status` from the scope of the class.

When you insert the `var` keyword before it, you are defining a new variable with the same name local to the `jsonLoaded()` function.

So, within your function it should be:

```
public function jsonLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    status = data[0].status;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot that helped me and i solved. i am really greatful for your help. Thankss